# Update database SQL by changing Spinner value

Tags: android

I am creating `database` named "Navigacija" witch consist of few `edittexts` and one `spinner`. Program manages to insert data, spinner value is successfully transferred to `String` in database and I manage to see all records correctly in dedicated `activity` by using list view and it also works.
Problem comes when I try to update record witch is called by long press from View record `activity`.
All fields are editable and correctly updated except "Vrsta broda" witch is actually drop down list of various ship types and spinner who is opening and giving me list to choose from ,but when showed again in list view, it isn't displayed as a text (String)...
Program doesn't crashes...

Here is my UpdateRecordNavigacija activity

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.DatePicker;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    import java.util.Calendar;
```

public class UpdateRecordNavigacija extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
private EditText etImeBrodaNavigacija, etDatumUkrcajaNavigacija, etDatumIskrcajaNavigacija,
        etVrstaBrodaNavigacija, etTipPogonaNavigacija, etKompanijaNavigacija, etAgencijaNavigacija;
private Button btnUpdateNavigacija;
private DataBaseHelper_Navigacija mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
String id, imeBroda, datumUkrcaja, datumIskrcaja, vrstaBroda, tipPogona, kompanija, agencija;
//Deklarirat Spinner
Spinner spinerTipPogona_UPDATE;
//Deklarirat za Date picker
Button btnDatumUkrcaja_UPDATE, btnDatumIskrcaja_UPDATE;
EditText etDatumUkrcaja_UPDATE, etDatumIskrcaja_UPDATE;
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_record_navigacija);
    // date picker
    btnDatumUkrcaja_UPDATE =(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja);
    btnDatumIskrcaja_UPDATE =(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_UPDATE_DatumIskrcaja);
    etDatumUkrcaja_UPDATE =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja);
    etDatumIskrcaja_UPDATE =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_UPDATE_DatumIskrcaja);

    btnDatumUkrcaja_UPDATE.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDatumIskrcaja_UPDATE.setOnClickListener(this);
    //Kreira spinner za odabir tip Pogona
    spinerTipPogona_UPDATE = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_UPDATE_TipPogona);
    final String [] tipPogona={"Motor","Steam","DFDE"};
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,tipPogona);
    spinerTipPogona_UPDATE.setAdapter(adapter);
    mHelper=new DataBaseHelper_Navigacija(this);
    dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    //capture sent parameter from previous screen
    id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("_ID");

    //initiate all textbox container to hold the data for the Navigacija
    etImeBrodaNavigacija=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_UPDATE_ImeBroda);
    etDatumUkrcajaNavigacija=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja);
    etDatumIskrcajaNavigacija=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_UPDATE_DatumIskrcaja);
    etVrstaBrodaNavigacija=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_VrstaBroda);
    spinerTipPogona_UPDATE = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_UPDATE_TipPogona);
    etKompanijaNavigacija=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_UPDATE_Kompanija);
    etAgencijaNavigacija=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_UPDATE_Agencija);

    //display field record inside the textboxes
    displayData();

    btnUpdateNavigacija =(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_UPDATE_AzurirajNavigaciju);
    btnUpdateNavigacija.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            //capture amendment
            imeBroda=etImeBrodaNavigacija.getText().toString();
            datumUkrcaja=etDatumUkrcajaNavigacija.getText().toString();
            datumIskrcaja=etDatumIskrcajaNavigacija.getText().toString();
            vrstaBroda=etVrstaBrodaNavigacija.getText().toString();
            spinerTipPogona_UPDATE.getSelectedItem();
            kompanija=etKompanijaNavigacija.getText().toString();
            agencija=etAgencijaNavigacija.getText().toString();


            saveData();
        }
    });//end btnsave setOnCLickCListener
}

//display single record of data from _ID
private void displayData() {

    //the SQL command to fetched all records from the table
    String sql="SELECT * FROM "
            + DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.TABLE_NAVIGACIJA +" WHERE _ID='"+id+"';";
    Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);

    //fetch the record
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //fetch each field and transfer to textbox
        imeBroda =mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_2));
        datumUkrcaja =mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_3));
        datumIskrcaja =mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_4));
        vrstaBroda =mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_5));
        tipPogona =mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_6));
        kompanija =mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_7));
        agencija =mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_8));


        //get data from field and transfer to EditText

        etImeBrodaNavigacija.setText(imeBroda);
        etDatumUkrcajaNavigacija.setText(datumUkrcaja);
        etDatumIskrcajaNavigacija.setText(datumIskrcaja);
        etVrstaBrodaNavigacija.setText(vrstaBroda);
        tipPogona = String.valueOf(spinerTipPogona_UPDATE);
        etKompanijaNavigacija.setText(kompanija);
        etAgencijaNavigacija.setText(agencija);

    }
    else{
        //do something here if no record fetched from database
        etImeBrodaNavigacija.setText(sql);
    }
}//end displayData


//save updated data
private void saveData(){
    //dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_2,imeBroda);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_3,datumUkrcaja );
    values.put(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_4,datumIskrcaja );
    values.put(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_5,vrstaBroda);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_6, String.valueOf(spinerTipPogona_UPDATE));
    values.put(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_7,kompanija);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_8,agencija);

    System.out.println("");

    //update database with new data
    dataBase.update(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.TABLE_NAVIGACIJA, values, DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_1+"="+id, null);

    //close database
    dataBase.close();
    finish();


}


//Date Picker
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == btnDatumUkrcaja_UPDATE) {

        // Get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog1 = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        etDatumUkrcaja_UPDATE.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog1.show();
    }
    if (v == btnDatumIskrcaja_UPDATE) {

        // Get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog2 = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        etDatumIskrcaja_UPDATE.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog2.show();
    }

}
```

}

Here are snapshots to give you idea...

[Update activity with its fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCUm1.jpg)

[Updated fields...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icL28.jpg)

[Final View ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK7t8.jpg)

### ...and my xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.robert.seamansbook.UnosNavigacije">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_UPDATE_ImeBroda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/hint_et_ImeBroda"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_UPDATE_ImeBroda"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_UPDATE_ImeBroda"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_UPDATE_ImeBroda"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:inputType="none|date"
    android:text="@string/hint_et_DatumUkrcaja" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bt_UPDATE_DatumIskrcaja"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bt_UPDATE_DatumIskrcaja"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:text="@string/hint_bt_UnosDatumUkrcaja" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_UPDATE_DatumIskrcaja"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/et_UPDATE_DatumIskrcaja"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/et_UPDATE_DatumIskrcaja"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_UPDATE_DatumIskrcaja"
    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
    android:text="@string/hint_bt_DatumIskrcaja" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_UPDATE_DatumIskrcaja"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/et_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/et_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/et_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/et_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja"
    android:ems="10"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_VrstaBroda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bt_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:editable="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:hint="@string/hint_et_VrstaBroda"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="17dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_UPDATE_Kompanija"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sp_UPDATE_TipPogona"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sp_UPDATE_TipPogona"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sp_UPDATE_TipPogona"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/hint_et_Kompanija"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_UPDATE_Agencija"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_UPDATE_Kompanija"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_UPDATE_Kompanija"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_UPDATE_Kompanija"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/hint_et_Agencija"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_UPDATE_AzurirajNavigaciju"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="AZURIRAJ NAVIGACIJU" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_VrstaBroda"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_VrstaBroda"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_VrstaBroda"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Tip pogona:" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sp_UPDATE_TipPogona"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8" />
```

Stucked here...please help on spinner and dropdown list...thnx

Answer (score 0):

Managed...completely forgot to set Adapter for drop-down list and spinner was just simple code mess i got my self in to... 
here is correct code  :)

---

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.DatePicker;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListPopupWindow;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import java.util.Calendar;
```

public class UpdateRecordNavigacija extends Activity implements OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

```
private EditText etImeBrodaNavigacija;
private EditText etDatumUkrcajaNavigacija;
private EditText etDatumIskrcajaNavigacija;
private EditText etVrstaBrodaNavigacija;
private EditText etKompanijaNavigacija;
private EditText etAgencijaNavigacija;
private Button btnUpdateNavigacija;
private DataBaseHelper_Navigacija mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
String id, imeBroda, datumUkrcaja, datumIskrcaja, vrstaBroda, tipPogona1, kompanija, agencija;

//Deklarirat Spinner
Spinner spinerTipPogona_UPDATE;

//Deklarirat za Date picker
Button btnDatumUkrcaja_UPDATE, btnDatumIskrcaja_UPDATE;
EditText etDatumUkrcaja_UPDATE, etDatumIskrcaja_UPDATE;
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;


//Deklarirat listu za vrstu brodova
ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow_VrstaBroda;

// ubaci zeljene Vrste Broda da se otvore u listi
String[] lista_VrstaBroda ={"Passenger ship","Oil Tanker","Chemical Tanker","Gas Tanker","Cargo ship","Container ship","Ro-Ro"};

@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_record_navigacija);

    // date picker
    btnDatumUkrcaja_UPDATE =(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja);
    btnDatumIskrcaja_UPDATE =(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_UPDATE_DatumIskrcaja);
    etDatumUkrcaja_UPDATE =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja);
    etDatumIskrcaja_UPDATE =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_UPDATE_DatumIskrcaja);

    btnDatumUkrcaja_UPDATE.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDatumIskrcaja_UPDATE.setOnClickListener(this);


    //Kreira listu za vrstu broda...

    etVrstaBrodaNavigacija = findViewById(
            R.id.et_VrstaBroda);
    listPopupWindow_VrstaBroda = new ListPopupWindow(
            UpdateRecordNavigacija.this);
    listPopupWindow_VrstaBroda.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(
            UpdateRecordNavigacija.this,
            R.layout.list_item, lista_VrstaBroda));
    listPopupWindow_VrstaBroda.setAnchorView(etVrstaBrodaNavigacija);

    //odredjuje velicinu popup prozora
    listPopupWindow_VrstaBroda.setWidth(10000);
    listPopupWindow_VrstaBroda.setHeight(400);

    listPopupWindow_VrstaBroda.setModal(true);
    listPopupWindow_VrstaBroda.setOnItemClickListener(
            UpdateRecordNavigacija.this);
    etVrstaBrodaNavigacija.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listPopupWindow_VrstaBroda.show();
        }
    });


    //Kreira spinner za odabir tip Pogona
    spinerTipPogona_UPDATE = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_UPDATE_TipPogona);
    final String [] tipPogona2={"Motor","Steam","DFDE"};
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,tipPogona2);
    spinerTipPogona_UPDATE.setAdapter(adapter);


    mHelper=new DataBaseHelper_Navigacija(this);
    dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    //capture sent parameter from previous screen
    id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("_ID");

    //initiate all textbox container to hold the data for the Navigacija
    etImeBrodaNavigacija=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_UPDATE_ImeBroda);
    etDatumUkrcajaNavigacija=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_UPDATE_DatumUkrcaja);
    etDatumIskrcajaNavigacija=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_UPDATE_DatumIskrcaja);
    spinerTipPogona_UPDATE = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_UPDATE_TipPogona);
    etKompanijaNavigacija=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_UPDATE_Kompanija);
    etAgencijaNavigacija=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_UPDATE_Agencija);

    //display field record inside the textboxes
    displayData();

    btnUpdateNavigacija =(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_UPDATE_AzurirajNavigaciju);
    btnUpdateNavigacija.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

            //capture amendment
            imeBroda=etImeBrodaNavigacija.getText().toString();
            datumUkrcaja=etDatumUkrcajaNavigacija.getText().toString();
            datumIskrcaja=etDatumIskrcajaNavigacija.getText().toString();
            vrstaBroda=etVrstaBrodaNavigacija.getText().toString();
            tipPogona1 = spinerTipPogona_UPDATE.getSelectedItem().toString();
            kompanija=etKompanijaNavigacija.getText().toString();
            agencija=etAgencijaNavigacija.getText().toString();


            saveData();
        }
    });//end btnsave setOnCLickCListener
}

//display single record of data from _ID
private void displayData() {

    //the SQL command to fetched all records from the table
    String sql="SELECT * FROM "
            + DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.TABLE_NAVIGACIJA +" WHERE _ID='"+id+"';";
    Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);

    //fetch the record
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //fetch each field and transfer to textbox
        imeBroda =mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_2));
        datumUkrcaja =mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_3));
        datumIskrcaja =mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_4));
        vrstaBroda =mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_5));
        tipPogona1 =mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_6));
        kompanija =mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_7));
        agencija =mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_8));


        //get data from field and transfer to EditText

        etImeBrodaNavigacija.setText(imeBroda);
        etDatumUkrcajaNavigacija.setText(datumUkrcaja);
        etDatumIskrcajaNavigacija.setText(datumIskrcaja);
        etKompanijaNavigacija.setText(kompanija);
        etAgencijaNavigacija.setText(agencija);

    }
    else{
        //do something here if no record fetched from database
        etImeBrodaNavigacija.setText(sql);
    }
}//end displayData


//save updated data
private void saveData(){
    //dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_2,imeBroda);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_3,datumUkrcaja );
    values.put(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_4,datumIskrcaja );
    values.put(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_5,vrstaBroda);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_6,tipPogona1);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_7,kompanija);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_8,agencija);

    System.out.println("");

    //update database with new data
    dataBase.update(DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.TABLE_NAVIGACIJA, values, DataBaseHelper_Navigacija.COL_1+"="+id, null);

    //close database
    dataBase.close();
    finish();


}


//Date Picker
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == btnDatumUkrcaja_UPDATE) {

        // Get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog1 = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        etDatumUkrcaja_UPDATE.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog1.show();
    }
    if (v == btnDatumIskrcaja_UPDATE) {

        // Get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog2 = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        etDatumIskrcaja_UPDATE.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog2.show();
    }

}

//Lista vrsta brodova
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    etVrstaBrodaNavigacija.setText(lista_VrstaBroda[position]);
    listPopupWindow_VrstaBroda.dismiss();
}
```

}